# Segment prefix when using pointers as function parameters

Tags: c, assembly, x86, segment

I have an assembler/c question. I just read about segment prefixes, for example ds:varX and so on. The prefix is important for the calculation of the logical address. I read too, that default is "ds" and as soon as you use the ebp register to calculate an address, "ss" is used. For code "cs" is default. That all makes sense.
Now I have the following in c:

```
int x; // some static var in ds

void test(int *p){
...
*p =5;

}

... main(){

test(&x);
//now x is 5
}
```

If you now think about the implemention of test-function... you get the pointer to x on the stack. If you want to dereference the pointer, you first get the pointer-value(address of x) from the stack and save it in eax for example. Then you can dereference eax to change the value of x. But how does the c-compiler know if the given pointer(address) references memory on the stack (for example if i call test from another function and push the address of a localvariable as parameter for test) or the data segment? How is the full logical address calculated? The function cannot know which segment the given address offset relates to..?!

Comment: Next time you might want to read a book published after 1990... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general case, on a segmented platform your can't just read the pointer value "into `eax`" as you suggest. On a segmented platform the pointer would generally hold both the segment value and offset value, meaning that reading such a pointer would imply initializing at least *two* registers - segment and offset - not just one `eax`.

But in specific cases it depends on so called the memory model. Compilers on segmented platforms supported several memory models.

For starters, for obvious reasons it does not matter *which* segment register you use as long as the segment register holds the correct value. For example, if `DS` and `ES` registers hold the same value inside, then `DS:<offset>` will point to the same location in memory as `ES:<offset>`.

In so called "tiny" memory model, for one example, *all* segment registers were holding the same value, i.e. everything - code, data, stack - would fit in one segment (which is why it was called "tiny"). In this memory model each pointer was just an offset in this segment and, of course, it simply didn't matter which segment register to use with that offset.

In "larger" memory models you could have separate segments for code (CS), stack (SS) and data (DS). But on such memory models pointer object would normally hold *both* the offset and segment part of the address inside of it. In your example pointer `p` would actually be a two-part object, holding both segment value and offset value at the same time. In order to dereference such pointer the compiler would generate the code that would read both segment and offset values from `p` and use both of them. For example, the segment value would be read into `ES` register, while the offset value would be read into `si` register. The code would then access `ES:[di]` in order to read `*p` value.

There were also "intermediate" memory models, when code would be stored in one segment (CS), while data and stack would both be stored in another segment, so `DS` and `SS` would hold the same value. On that platform, obviously, there was no need to differentiate between `DS` and `SS`.

In the largest memory models you could have multiple data segments. In this case it is rather obvious that proper data addressing in segmented mode is not really a matter of choosing the proper segment register (as you seem to believe), but rather a matter of taking pretty much *any* segment register and initializing it with the correct value before performing the access.

Comment: I understand, but if I write the "test" function in assembler is it usual that you have to push such a "complex" pointer object? Are there alternatives?

Comment: @Martin: Again, it will simply depend on what your `test` function *expects* as `p`. If it expects a complex object, then you have to push a complex object. If it expects just an offset, then you have to push just an offset.

Comment: I guess what you explain here is all about the old 16-bit registers (you mention __di__ here) while OP is probably interested in 32-bit ones (mentioning __ebp__). When using 32-bit architecture, pointers probably never include segment registers (that would make them 48-bit) so DS must be equal to SS in order for pointers to work.

Comment: @anatolyg: 32 bit code can use far pointers. It's just that using a flat memory model is easier, so most modern OSes use that, or something pretty close.

Comment: @anatolyg: Well, I thought about it differently. Since OP even mentions segment registers, that would imply that he's *not* working with flat memory model. If he is working with flat memory model, then it is just a modern 64-bit version of "tiny" memory model I described in my answer. Additionally, x64 architecture is perfectly capable of using "non-tiny" memory models. It is that compilers believe that "64-bit tiny" should be enough for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

What AndreyT described was what happened on DOS days. These days, modern operating systems use the so called [flat memory model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_memory_model) (or rather something very similar), in which all (protected mode) segments are setup so that they all can access the whole address space (i.e: they have a base of 0 and a limit = the whole address space).

Comment: The whole virtual address space. :-)

Comment: @R.. In this case I think it's the whole linear address space ;P

Comment: A modern operating system with a flat memory model is not offering flat unlimited access to physical memory. It's offering a process flat access to its own virtual address space.

Comment: @R.. I've nitpicked too much. On x86, addresses after segmentation but before paging are called linear addresses.

Answer (score 1):

On a machine with a segmented memory model, the C implementation must do one of the following things to be conformant:

- Store the full address (with segment) in each pointer, OR
- Ensure that all stack addresses that will be used for variables whose addresses are taken can be accessed via the data segment, either at the same relative address or via some magic offset the compiler can apply when taking the address of local variables, OR
- Not use the stack for local variables whose addresses are taken, and perform a hidden malloc/free on every function entry/return (with special handling for `longjmp`!).

Perhaps there are other ways of doing it, but these are the only ones I can think of. Segmented memory models were really pretty disagreeable with C, and they were abandoned for good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation is the legacy artifact of the Intel 16-bit 8086 processor. In reality, you probably operate in [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), where everything is just a linear address. Compile with `-S` flag and see the resulting assembly.

Comment: Actually, on x86 everything is a virtual address, whose offset, by virtue of the segment bases being set to 0, maps 1:1 to a linear address, which then gets mapped via paging to a physical address.

Comment: And how is that different from what I said?

Comment: It has an additional layer of indirection. See RFC1925.

Answer (score 0):

Since you move the address to eax before dereferencing it, it defaults to the ds segment. However, as Nikolai mentioned, in user level code the segments probably all point to the same address.

Answer (score 0):

Under x86, direct usage of the stack will use the stack segment, but indirect usage treats it as a data segment. You can see this if you disassemble a pointer dereference and write to a stack section pointer. Under x86 cs, ss and ds are treated pretty much the same(atleast in non kernel modes) due to linear addressing. the intel reference manuals should also have a section on segment addressing