# How segment prefix mov/lea to register?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, segment

I know that in tiny memory model, Segment registers are holding the same value. (except %fs, %gs).There is a relative topic here:
[Segment prefix when using pointers as function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866481/segment-prefix-when-using-pointers-as-function-parameters). 
But what if segment registers are holding different value? For example, we may pass an address to a function through a pointer:

```
mov %fs:(%rax),%rsi
mov %ds:(%rax),%rsi
```

Considering `%fs`and `%ds` are holding different base addresses. And a function may use both kinds of references. So is the function able to distinguish them?And what `%rsi` register actually holds? Or the situation does not exist?

Comment: What is "tiny memory model" in x86_64? It was used like this in 16b mode, but there the segment value is part of physical address (added to bits 4 to 19 of final 20b address). | It's not clear how you pass the pointer to such code (in `rax`?), but if `fs` differs `ds`, then each `mov` will use different logical memory address (it still may map to the same physical address, if the memory is mapped that way, but from logical point of view those instructions are accessing different memory, first one `fs:rax`, other one `ds:rax`... whatever that means in x86_64 (some index into descriptor table?))

Comment: Both assembly statements read a 64-bit value from a location in memory and store in RSI. Neither statement loads the address of a function into RSI unless the address of that function was previously stored at the location being read. The location in memory being read by the the first instruction is at linear address `FS.base + RAX`, where `FS.base` is the base of the FS segment. The location in memory read by the second is at linear address `RAX`. The base of the DS segment is always 0 in 64-bit mode.

Comment: @Ped7g  I saw "tiny memory model" in another topic, it means the segment registers share same value. I actually want to know how the function knows which segment register should be use to access the data, because the address is passed from a single register. I'm sorry that my code is confusing...

Comment: Depends on the mode you are in. The segment registers are important in 16b real mode (DOS) (as you have only 16b for offsets = 64ki of memory max). In 64b mode (in linux) the user-land memory model is "flat memory mapping": one 64b number is enough to address all of your memory (up to 2^64 limit) and you don't need to override instructions by segments, the default `ds`/`ss` are both set to the same value, so you use only 64b offsets. I'm not into OS dev, so I don't know how it looks in kernel-land, maybe they use more tricky memory mappings. fs/gs may have extra meaning to help parallelism.

Answer (score 4):

Under x64 the `ss`, `cs`, `ds` and `es` segments all hold the same value, which is 0.
The `fs` and `gs` segments are used for a different purpose.

**Windows**
`fs` points to the 32-bits thread information block of the current process.
`gs` points to the 64-bits TIB of the current process.

**Linux**
In a 32-bit kernel `fs` is the base of the per-cpu data area. In a
64-bit kernel `gs` points to the pda (processor data area). The pda is a
single structure, whereas per-cpu data is a section that per-cpu
variables get put into.

`fs` is used when running 32-bit code on a 64-bit operating system (e.g. WoW64).

Registers in x86 used to have special purposes, but nowadays most registers are general purpose.

`rsi` can be used for any purpose whatsoever.
Only in the string instructions does it have special meaning.
In that context it is used to point to the source (e.g. [movsb](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVS:MOVSB:MOVSW:MOVSD:MOVSQ.html)).

> So is the function able to distinguish them?

By prefixing the instruction with a segment prefix.

```
mov rsi,[rax]     // rsi = memory(rax).
xor eax,eax       //rax =0 (remember 32 bit instructions zero extend)
mov rsi,[gs:rax]  //load the first 8 bytes of the 64-bit TIB into rsi.
```

**About lea**
Lea does not access memory, it merely does calculations without altering the flags.
Often these calculations involve calculating pointers, but it can also be general arithmetic.
Putting a segment prefix in front of a lea makes no sense and has no effect.

Comment: What operating system? In the case of Windows, at least some and perhaps all per thread values such as the seed value for rand() get mapped from fs:... into the virtual address space for a thread, after which a normal pointer can be used. Since the threads in a process share virtual address space, each thread variable would be accessed via a different pointer value.

Comment: So even if `[gs:rax]` and `[ds:rcx]` actually hold same linear address, the function has to handle them separately, with two pieces of code?